# What are the No Mans Sky base complexity limits of update 3.10?

Tags: no-mans-sky

[This recent update seems to increase the limits on base complexity and possibly a larger build radius.](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Update_3.10#Richer_Base_Construction)

> Richer Base Construction
>
> Base building on next-generation consoles can reach more ambitious heights, with the ability to construct larger and more complex builds.

I believe the old base limit was something close to 3000 per base and 20000 across all bases.  The build limit was 1000 distance units from the base computer.  What are the new limits? What has the update actually changed?